# see my background-image: url() inside of other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a div with background-image: url() inside of 2 div more but i cant see the image and i dont know why, although can see my background-image: url() when i put this on my firs div. Does anyone know how can fix this? thanks :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
.content-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  background-color: beige;
}
#projects-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}
.inner-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100.1%;
  min-height: 100.1%;
}

.project.x4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(0.86624 * 29vw);
  float: left;
   background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">

    <div id="projects-wrapped">

     <article class="project x4">

        <div class="inner-wrapper">

          <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(FOTOS/CHIPS_AHOY_STYLEFRAME_FR_v02.3.jpg); background-position: center;background-size: cover;"> </div>

        </div>
      </article>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Try an absolute address, codepen (or SO), doesn't have the same directory structure as your server, and most likely also it has not stored that image anywhere.

Comment: Your div with background has height is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have typo error in your id name `#projects-wrapper`. In html, you are writing it as `projects-wrapped`.
And you should give height to your divs else it will take 0 height if the content inside it doesn't have height.